# C++ vector::clear() - order of destruction?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I've searched around and not found anything - does C++ give any guarantee on the order that items in a std::vector will be deleted when calling vector::clear()?

I have a vector with some items which depend on other items in the vector, so need to ensure it is cleared LIFO.  FIFO would be fine - I can reverse the vector before calling clear().

Comment: Do the *destructors* depend on the linked elements? If not, then the order of destruction would not matter.

Comment: The [requirements for a sequence container](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#tab:containers.sequence.requirements) just say `clear()` destroys all elements, the container's `empty()` returns `true` and the complexity is linear. The section on `std::vector` doesn't add anything to that so it seems the order is unspecified.

Comment: @errorika, sorry I should have been more clear - yes the destructors (in some cases) depend on other elements in the container.

Comment: Vectors are not LIFO/FIFO containers, they don't  have a record of insertion order.

Comment: Use a container that preserve the insertion order, like std::stack

Comment: @Brad How are the elements linked to each other? A bare pointer? Something else?

Comment: @Amadeus `std::stack` doesn't even have a `clear` operation. And doesn't give any further guarantees about destruction order of elements upon destruction of the stack.

Comment: @eerorika -- but `std::stack` **does** keep track of insertion order; `while (!empty) pop()` will clear the stack with destruction in LIFO order.

Comment: @PeteBecker You can achieve the same without the `stack` wrapper too using `pop_back`. Brad doesn't describe what other operations they need, but I suppose if no other operations are needed `stack` could be a good choice.

Comment: Do your dependent objects continue to function if they are *copied*, *moved* or *swapped*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [sequence container requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts)(`std::vector` is one of those) the standard only says this about `clear()`:

> Destroys all elements in `a`. Invalidates all references, pointers, and
>   iterators referring to the elements of a and may invalidate the
>   past-the-end iterator.
>
> Ensures: `a.empty()` returns `true`.
>
> Complexity: Linear.

So no, you get no guarantees on the order of destruction.